Android ForegroundService in Multiple Screen of Jetpack Compose
at the moment i am developing Music Player in Jetpack Compose. I want to ask how can i handle using MusicService in multiple screens? I mean i have to be able change service state from my Home Screen and Player Screen. I have tried using viewmodel but it lacks context when i initialize Service in viewmodel.

Try companion class to create singleton, then use flow or livedata inside to send or subscribe wiseverse on service or UI.

You must use a started-bound service with a combination of DisposableEffect to subscribe to the foreground service binder.
